# anchor when extended not working

Tags: javafx, extend, pane

I created my own chart with x and y axises.  I found the present choices of charts did not suite my needs.  I have managed to built my chart to my likings and now I would like to add all the components to an object that extends AnchorPane. The end results is that my code compiles with no errors, no runtime errors but I don't see any of my panes that I created.  I was wondering what the correct procedure is to extend AnchorPane.

This is the code inside my class that extends Application. Works like a charm:

```
        Vector <String[]>  v = new Vector<String[]>();
        double highest_high = 0;
        double lowest_low = 0;
        AnchorPane anchorpane = new AnchorPane();


        double xaxisHeight = 20;
        double yaxisWidth = 60;
        double chartYAdjustment = 40;
        double barGap = 3;
        double bars = 15;
        final Chart chart = new Chart(v, yaxisWidth, xaxisHeight, highest_high, lowest_low, chartYAdjustment, barGap);
        final YAxis yaxis = new YAxis(yaxisWidth, highest_high, lowest_low);
        final XAxis xaxis = new XAxis(xaxisHeight, barGap, bars);

        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(yaxis, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(yaxis, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(yaxis, 20.0);        


        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(xaxis, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(xaxis, 60.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(xaxis, 0.0);     

        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(chart, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(chart, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(chart, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(chart, 0.0);

        anchorpane.getChildren().addAll(chart, yaxis, xaxis);

        Scene s = new Scene(anchorpane, 800, 400, Color.BLACK);
        stage.setScene(s);
        stage.show();
```

When I put the code inside a class that extends AnchorPane:

```
public class Main extends AnchorPane{

    public void Main(){
        Vector <String[]>  v = new Vector<String[]>();
        double highest_high = 0;
        double lowest_low = 0;      

        double xaxisHeight = 20;
        double yaxisWidth = 60;
        double chartYAdjustment = 40;
        double barGap = 3;
        double bars = 15;
        final Chart chart = new Chart(v, yaxisWidth, xaxisHeight, highest_high, lowest_low, chartYAdjustment, barGap);
        final YAxis yaxis = new YAxis(yaxisWidth, highest_high, lowest_low);
        final XAxis xaxis = new XAxis(xaxisHeight, barGap, bars);

        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(yaxis, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(yaxis, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(yaxis, 20.0);        


        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(xaxis, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(xaxis, 60.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(xaxis, 0.0);     

        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(chart, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(chart, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(chart, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(chart, 0.0);

        getChildren().addAll(chart, yaxis, xaxis);
```

And then in my class that extends Application I have:

```
Main main = new Main();
Scene s = new Scene(main, 800, 400, Color.BLACK);
            stage.setScene(s);
            stage.show();
```

It only displays a black window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out what I was doing wrong.  I have "void" in my constructor call making a method.